# What is the correct strategy for handling multiple SQL Server databases in the same instance with the same name (each one for a different country)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the same named SQL Server 2008R2 databases multiple times in a single instance with the only difference being that each database is prefixed with a CountryCode (i.e. the databases are for different countries).

I need to define a strategy for coding stored procedures in order for them to work across multiple databases (countries) in the same instance.

The schema name is already used, hence the prefixing of the database names.

So far the ideas I have come up with are:

including the country code prefix as an argument such that:

1. a 'case' or 'if statement can be used in the stored procedure,
2. using dynamic sql to concatenate the country code and the database name

neither seems particularly ideal, and the option of creating different instances has been ruled out.

Comment: what rdbms? Oracle? SQL server? MySQL? PostgreSQL? other?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be done, but read about database Alias.
Maybe you can create some mechanism to work on the Alias and change the alias as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a simple example of what your code needs to do?

This doesn't seem to be a problem if you already know the database names and when/why you'd need to query them.

Unless you need to do things dynamically (ie. only query specific databases based on input parameters).

Comment: example: a single stored procedure that would work across multiple databases, each database name prefixed with its own country, rather than maintaining multiple copies of the same procedure.

Comment: If you only reference tables from within the database, then that wouldn't be a problem. Just remove any database prefix in your FROM clauses and it should run on all the DBs assuming the schema and other database objects match up.